# Azure Cloudfunction with Servicebus and exponential retries

Tags: azure-functions, servicebus

I'm making an azure cloudfunction with nodejs that I want to retry exponentially when it fails to process a message.

This is the host.json file, that I assumed would do the trick. However it seems that clientRetryOptions has to do with the background service bus message collecting and retryability of that process not the function I am running.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "clientRetryOptions": {
        "mode": "exponential",
        "tryTimeout": "00:01:00",
        "delay": "00:00:10.80",
        "maxDelay": "00:20:00",
        "maxRetries": 3
      },
      "prefetchCount": 0,
      "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:09:55"
}
```

My question is, if that's what the case. How do I exponentially delay the retry of my function code during failures?

pseudo code:

1. get message
2. throw error -> message gets put back into topic
3. exponentially wait every attempt, instead of the default pull message right away from the topic.

A terrible solution would be to count attempts and sleep the function for each attempt count.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, if that's what the case. How do I exponentially delay
> the retry of my function code during failures?

**Plan your retry strategy**
According to Microsoft documents.

> Several Functions bindings extensions provide built-in support for
> retries. In addition, the runtime lets you define retry policies for
> Timer and Event Hubs triggered functions. To learn more, see
> [Retries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=fixed-delay%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#retries). For triggers that don't provide retry behaviors, you may want to
> implement your own retry scheme.

Retries :- Two type of retries available in azure functions. First is Build in [retry behaviors of individula trigger extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=fixed-delay,in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#retries) and second [Retry Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=fixed-delay,in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#retry-policies).

Referenced Microsoft Document [Click Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=fixed-delay,in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp) on Azure Function error handling and Retries.

Comment: You mention timers and event hubs, but my question is specifically for Service Bus triggers and delays between receiving and processing failed messages.